# convert to multiindex dataframe w/horizontal display and rename columns

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

let's say i have the following code:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,4), columns=['A','B','C','D'])
df1['dataframe'] = 'df1'
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,4), columns=['A','B','C','D'])
df2['dataframe'] = 'df2'
df = pd.concat([df1, df2])
df.reset_index().set_index(['dataframe','index'])
```

this will return me a dataframe with 2 levels of indices, 'dataframe' and 'index'. i'm not sure what the correct term is but visually, the first index spans across rows as opposed to columns.

there are 2 operations i would like to perform on this dataframe that i am struggling with.

1) i would like to rename the columns in each "sub-dataframe" to something different, taken from a different list and apply them accordingly based on the first index previously assigned. i have tried the following but it does not work if i display "df" again:

```
new_cols = ['df1', 'df2']
for i,x in enumerate(new_cols):
    old_cols = df.loc[x].columns.tolist()
    df.loc[x].rename(columns={col_label: '{}_{}'.format(x,col_label) for col_label in old_cols}, inplace=True)
```

so, to be clear, instead of A,B,C,D i'd like df1_A...df1_D and df2_A...df2_D

2) i would like to re-orient this dataframe such that they span across the columns and so i would be scrolling across in order to view each "sub-dataframe" rather than up and down.

i've consulted the pandas API but still not able to get this right.

Comment: Hey laszlopanaflex, i saw a line in the pandas cookbook which makes a horizontal multiindex, is that what you wanted? I added that line to my answer

Answer (score 0):

OK, from that starting point you firstly want to call `reset_index` again like so:

```
df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Now you should have only one level in the index, and the columns `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, and `dataframe`.

Now pivot by the `dataframe` column:

```
df_pivot = df.pivot(columns='dataframe')
```

You now have a dataframe with hierarchically-indexed columns, which will allow you to scroll across and see `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D` at the top level, with the `df1` and `df2` just underneath.

If you're just wanting to explore the data it's actually best to stop there. You'll be able to index in a natural way without renaming columns, and it'll be easy to explore the data by scrolling horizontally. To index into `A` and `df1` values, you'd write:

```
df_pivot['A']['df1']
```

That's a natural syntax. But if you really did want to add in the underscores, you could add them like so:

```
df_pivot.columns = ['_'.join(col[::-1]).strip() for col in df_pivot.columns.values]
```

Because the pivot table's columns are represented by a MultiIndex, `df_pivot.columns.values` returns an array of tuples. Each tuple is something like `('A','df1')` so if you want column names of the form `df1_A` you do need the `[::1]` I've added there, so that you join the tuple members in reverse order. If you're happy with the other order for column names (`A_df1`), then you can remove the reverse step:

```
df_pivot.columns = ['_'.join(col).strip() for col in df_pivot.columns.values]
```

Comment: i'm not able to see how this works. i assume you are suggesting that i do NOT include the line from my original snippet: df.reset_index().set_index(['dataframe','index']). otherwise, the "dataframe" column (which is really an index) disappears altogether.

Comment: That's right, you don't need that last line in your original snippet. Keep `dataframe` as a column so that you can call `df.pivot` as shown here.

Comment: this still doesn't work unfortunately. it returns an error ValueError: cannot label index with a null key. i am in python 2.7

Answer (score 0):

Using the `dataframe` generated by the original code snippet, we can create two separate `dataframes` based on which `dataframe` they belong to, then drop the `"dataframe"` column from both. We then assign the new column names to each of the `columns` properties of the two dataframes. At last, we pass in the list of `df2` column names into `df1` and since it doesn't exist, pandas creates new columns and we assign `df2`'s values to these new columns.

Edit: Got a line which makes a column multiindex from [pandas cookbook](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/cookbook.html#multiindexing)

```
df1 = df[df["dataframe"] == "df1"].copy().drop("dataframe",axis = 1)
df2 = df[df["dataframe"] == "df2"].copy().drop("dataframe", axis = 1)
df1.columns = ["df1_" + df1.columns]
df2.columns = ["df2_" + df2.columns]
df1[df2.columns] = df2
df1.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([tuple(c.split('_')) for c in df1.columns]); 
print df1
```

Output (New):

```
        df1                                     df2                      \
          A         B         C         D         A         B         C   
0 -0.228363  0.675313 -0.076193 -0.805547  0.920632  0.789152  0.275401   
1  0.145603  0.422236  0.623796  0.233534  2.338283 -1.033269 -0.334333   
2 -0.526696  0.307727  0.478437 -0.068488 -0.475583 -0.802997 -0.059091   
3 -1.676880 -0.272451 -0.777794  0.490290  1.456024  0.340962 -0.436860   
4  1.203065 -0.198686 -1.065447  1.188931 -1.140757  0.046975 -2.596953   
5 -0.603939  0.734130 -0.321634  0.150161  2.228873  0.748693 -0.300975   
6  1.028938  0.114437  0.268499  0.260428 -1.896507  0.136147  0.004577   
7 -1.329070 -0.901562 -1.401573  0.715426 -1.711233  0.420301  0.643113   
8  2.033646 -0.550192  1.532104 -1.196995 -0.004135 -1.334320  0.110115   
9 -0.818145 -1.240037  0.880706 -0.625155 -0.672653  0.365357 -0.864840   


          D  
0 -0.888626  
1 -0.952065  
2  0.249387  
3  0.952315  
4 -1.804463  
5 -0.428231  
6 -0.257906  
7  1.551899  
8  0.054855  
9  0.679394
```

Comment: this does not have any multiindex properties though?

Comment: Well, he says `instead of A,B,C,D i'd like df1_A...df1_D and df2_A...df2_D` for the columns. So it doesn't seem like there's supposed to be a multi-index after conversion, although i'm not too sure either. Edit: Oh i didn't realize you were OP. Okay nevermind, i thought you didn't want a multi-index.

Comment: yes the idea is to still have the multi-index structure, but "transposed" and with the underlying columns renamed. any help appreciated!